# Drupal 7 user register form in overlay on page load

Tags: 7, users, modal-dialogs, javascript

One of my requirements is to show the user registration form in an overlay kind of interface.

From the Examples module issue queue, comment #14 http://drupal.org/node/930058 I found a module, learned the hook_admin_paths() and hook_admin_paths_alter(). I installed that module in my local test site. Added `"user/register"` path to `$paths` of `hook_admin_paths()` and granted permissions to use overlay. It works pretty much as expected with the click event however my requirement is to trigger the overlay for onpageload event.

I tried calling a js script which would trigger click event from `hook_overlay_parent_initialize()` and module's info file by settings `scripts[] = myoverlay.js`.

The js script looks as below,

```
(function ($) {

Drupal.behaviors.loginLoad = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    alert("trigger client event"); // works 
    $(".menu-589 a").attr("title", "click"); // works
    $(".menu-589 a").trigger("click"); 
    // This one didn't work. Tried triggerHandler() and click() as well.
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

My jQuery expertise is very limited. I'm trying to figure out how the overlay fires for onclick event.

From what I learned the paths to be opens in overlay are defined in `Drupal.settings.overlay.paths.admin`. And overlay-parent.js and jQuery BBQ does some tricks to show things in modal window.

Any help to figure out this will be appreciated.

On a side note : For Drupal 6 projects I have used modal frame api module often with onclick event. This module doesn't seems to be available for Drupal 7 and it is going to be deprecated in favor of overlay in core. Is overlay an API module ?  It doesn't appear to be the case from my experience.

Comment: I think I'd try to do this without custom code. Have you tried using [Lightbox2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) or [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox)? Both provide a way to simply add an argument to a link or a class on a div and do a popup/overlay.

Comment: You also might want to look at the [Fancy Login](http://drupal.org/project/fancy_login) module, which does this for user/login. I'm sure you could do the same with registration (and offer a patch to this module) as long as the form is relatively small.

Comment: rfay, thanks for your reply. I have been able to partially achieve it with colorbox module however I have some problems I'm trying to solve it one by one. I will keep you posted on the problems and fixes when I'm done.

Comment: Have you given a look at CTools? It exposes a simple modal window API.

Answer (score 1):

I you need something like this site http://www.hospitalsreview.com/ has done for the sign up then you should try my module it will surely help you as you can see it is working on my site.

[Sign Up Module](http://www.mediafire.com/?189sssv4svmyy91)

Comment: The sing-up which http://www.hospitalsreview.com/ can be easily achieved using https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms.
Works great for registration form, login form as well as comments form.
Hope this works out for you..
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For [Flocknote](http://www.flocknote.com/), I had to put the registration form/page inside an overlay that loads for users who are not logged-in on certain pages. Here's an example: http://www.flocknote.com/community

You'll notice that, when you visit that page as an anonymous user, there are some URL params added, namely `?reg=true#overlay=register/overlay/246`. Adding the '#overlay=path/to/node' should make a page open in the overlay. (I can't remember if what else I was doing with the 'reg' variable.)

I basically run a bit of code inside a custom module's `hook_init()` implementation that says: "If the user is anonymous, and this is a network node home page, `drupal_goto()` the same URL, but with the fragment `overlay=register/overlay/[nid]` added on."

This seems to work great for me.